# Is there a name for this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Say we have a graph $G=(V(G),E(G))$, where $V(G)$ is the vertex set of $G$ and $E(G)$ is the edge set of $G$. Define a graph $H$ which preserves all adjacency relations, $V(G)=E(H)$ and $V(H)=E(G)$. Is there a name for $H$?

I should mention that I am not entirely sure that the previous definition is correct, so here's an intuitive explanation on what I'm thinking of. For example, say we have $G=C_k$ (the cycle of order $k$), so that $V(G)=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$ and $E$ consists of $v_iv_{i+1}$ (with indices taken modulo $k$). Then the graph $H$ in this case would be again just $C_k$ with different vertex/edge labellings.

As another example, the path of order two $G=P_2$ would have a corresponding graph $H$ which has one vertex (since $G$ has one edge) and two edges (since $G$ has two vertices). In this case, however, I'm not sure that $H$ is well defined since it's not clear what two vertices these two edges are incident with.

So, is this a well-established concept for most graphs? When is it not well defined? Is there a name for this graph $H$ corresponding to $G$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the graph with one vertex and two loops? This graph is $4$-regular, but doesn't the graph with two vertices and one edge incident with both vertices fit the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of $E(H)$ runs into problems with non-degree-2 vertices in $G$, as mentioned in comments. But if this change is made to the definition of $E(H)$:

> two vertices of $H$ have an edge between iff the corresponding edges in $G$ share a vertex

then $H$ is the **[line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph)** of $G$.

Comment: Is there a proof that the definition I gave doesn't work if $G$ isn't $2$-regular? Also, why does the graph I provided in the comments previously not work? Many thanks in advance

Comment: @Lucas You showed yourself that it doesn't work on $P_2$. An edge can't dangle!

Comment: I don't see how the "dangling edge" issue generalises though. I can tell why there are issues if for some $v\in V(G)$, $d(v)=1$, but why can't it work for $d(v)=4$ for the graph I gave? Could you explain why it doesn't fit the requirements?

Comment: @Lucas At a degree-4 vertex in $G$, connecting the four edges that lead into it in $H$ would be ambiguous.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. Is it right if I rephrase the statement as "$H$ is well-defined iff every edge $e\in E(G)$ is incident with exactly $2$ distinct vertices"? This allows for the possibility of loops.

Comment: @Lucas It would be well defined if all _vertices_ $v$ in $G$ had degree 2.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see why the graph $H$ with two vertices and exactly one edge between them doesn't satisfy the requirement for the graph $G$ with one vertex and two loops. There is the right number of edges and vertices, for one.

Comment: @Lucas A one-vertex two-loop graph $G$ would correspond to a two-vertex graph $H$ with four edges, one for each endpoint incidence. Normally simple graphs are assumed, so that $G$ would not qualify. For $P_2$, your construction should logically lead to just a single isolated vertex, which is also the line graph.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I have accepted your answer.